# MATLAB command simplify: use multiple or just one

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am currently using the MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox to simplify and reduce non-linear equations of substantial size. Therefore, I use the MATLAB command `simplify` extensively. For the current situation, I need to simplify many 4-by-4 symbolic matrices.

For instance, I want to check whether two symbolic matrices (`A` and `B`, both 4-by-4) are equivalent representations of the same matrix; this is my current solution:

```
diff_AB = simplify(A-B);
```

As `A` and `B` are 4-by-4 square matrices, I can also decide to split the rows of the matrices and compute the symbolic difference of each row.

In terms of computational effort and the amount of simplification, what is the best way to handle these symbolic matrices?

Comment: have you tried to time it?

Comment: Have you also tried `isequal` and `isAlways`? You'll probably want to apply `assumptions` to your variables too to improve performance and ensure you get the equalities you expect. What works well will probably depend on the size and complexity of your inputs and, possibly, how much RAM you have.

Comment: I managed to determine the row that was the most computionally complex for MATLAB to simplify and applied one separate simplify-statement on that row. After that, I applied a general simplification statement for the whole operation. This seem to lead to the best result in terms of computational time.